# Snakemake: MissingInputException in snakemake pipeline

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I'm trying a SnakeMake pipeline and I'm stucked on an error I really don't understand.

I've got a directory (`raw_data`) in which I have the input files :

```Bash
ll /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/raw_data
total 41M
drwxrwxr-x  2 nico nico 4,0K mars   6 16:09 ./
drwxrwxr-x 11 nico nico 4,0K mars   6 16:14 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 nico nico  15M févr. 27 12:21 sampleA_R1.fastq.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 nico nico  19M févr. 27 12:22 sampleA_R2.fastq.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 nico nico 3,4M févr. 27 12:21 sampleB_R1.fastq.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 nico nico 4,3M févr. 27 12:22 sampleB_R2.fastq.gz
```

This directory contains 4 files for 2 samples.
I created a config json file for the SnakeMake pipeline named `config_snakemake_Optimal_mapping_BaL.json`:

```
{
    "fastqExtension": "fastq.gz",
    "fastqDir": "/home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/raw_data",
    "outputDir": "/home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/mapping_BaL",
    "logDir": "logs",
    "reference": {
        "fasta": "/home/nico/labo/references/genomes/HIV1/BaL_AY713409/BaL_AY713409.fasta",
        "index": "/home/nico/labo/references/genomes/HIV1/BaL_AY713409/BaL_AY713409.fasta.bwt"
    }
}
```

And finally the SnakeMake file `snakefile_bwa_samtools.py`:

```Python
import subprocess
from os.path import join

### Globals ---------------------------------------------------------------------

# A Snakemake regular expression matching fastq files.

SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards(join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R1."+config["fastqExtension"]))
print(SAMPLES)

### Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pipeline output files
rule all:
    input: expand(join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bam.bai"), sample=SAMPLES)

# Reads alignment on reference genome and BAM file creation
rule bwa_mem_to_bam:
    input:
        index = config["reference"]["index"],
        fasta = config["reference"]["fasta"],
        fq1_ID = "{sample}_R1."+config["fastqExtension"],
        fq2_ID = "{sample}_R2."+config["fastqExtension"],
        fq1 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R1."+config["fastqExtension"]),
        fq2 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R2."+config["fastqExtension"])
    output:
        temp(join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bamUnsorted"))
    version:
        subprocess.getoutput(
        "man bwa | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 2"
        )
    log:
        join(config["outputDir"], config["logDir"], "{sample}.bwa_mem.log")
    message:
        "Alignment of {input.fq1_ID} and {input.fq2_ID} on {input.fasta} with BWA version {version}."
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input.fasta} {input.fq1} {input.fq2} 2> {log} | samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"

# Sorting the BAM files on genomic positions
rule bam_sort:
    input:
        join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bamUnsorted")
    output:
        join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bam")
    log:
        join(config["outputDir"], config["logDir"],  "{sample}.samtools_sort.log")
    version:
        subprocess.getoutput(
            "samtools --version | "
            "head -1 | "
            "cut -d' ' -f2"
        )
    message:
        "Genomic sorting of {input} with samtools version {version}."
    shell:
        "samtools sort -f {input} {output} 2> {log}"

# Indexing the BAM files
rule bam_index:
    input:
        join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bam")
    output:
        join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bam.bai")
    message:
        "Indexing {input}."
    shell:
        "samtools index {input}"
```

I run this pipeline:

```Bash
snakemake --cores 3 --snakefile /home/nico/labo/scripts/pipeline_illumina/snakefile_bwa_samtools.py --configfile /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/snakemake_config_files/config_snakemake_Optimal_mapping_BaL.json
```

and I've got the following error outputs:

```Bash
['sampleB', 'sampleA']
MissingInputException in line 18 of /home/nico/labo/scripts/pipeline_illumina/snakefile_bwa_samtools.py:
Missing input files for rule bwa_mem_to_bam:
sampleB_R1.fastq.gz
sampleB_R2.fastq.gz
```

or depending the moment:

```Bash
['sampleB', 'sampleA']
PeriodicWildcardError in line 40 of /home/nico/labo/scripts/pipeline_illumina/snakefile_bwa_samtools.py:
The value _unsorted in wildcard sample is periodically repeated (sampleB_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted_unsorted). This would lead to an infinite recursion. To avoid this, e.g. restrict the wildcards in this rule to certain values.
```

The samples are correctly detected as they appear in the list (first line of kind of outputs) and I'm surely messing around with the wildcards in the rule `bwa_mem_to_bam`, but I really don't get why..
Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hugo for checking my code and your explanation, it makes sense!
I finally get a flash idea waking up this morning (the best ones), and realized that I neglected the `params` part of the rule, fq1_ID and fq2_ID are not inputs but params..
I changed the code to that:

```Python
rule bwa_mem_to_bam:
input:
    index = config["reference"]["index"],
    fasta = config["reference"]["fasta"],
    fq1 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R1.fastq.gz"),
    fq2 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R2.fastq.gz")
output:
    temp(join(config["outputDir"],"{sample}_unsorted.bam"))
params:
    fq1_ID = "{sample}_R1.fastq.gz",
    fq2_ID = "{sample}_R2.fastq.gz",
    ref_ID = os.path.basename(config["reference"]["fasta"])
version:
    subprocess.getoutput(
    "man bwa | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 2"
    )
log:
    join(config["outputDir"], config["logDir"], "{sample}.bwa_mem.log")
message:
    "Alignment of {params.fq1_ID} and {params.fq2_ID} on {params.ref_ID} with BWA version {version}."
shell:
    "bwa mem {input.fasta} {input.fq1} {input.fq2} 2> {log} | samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"
```

And it works just fine!

```Bash
snakemake --cores 3 --snakefile /home/nico/labo/scripts/pipeline_illumina/snakefile_bwa_samtools.py --configfile /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/snakemake_config_files/config_snakemake_Optimal_mapping_BaL.json 
Provided cores: 3
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    2   bam_index
    2   bam_sort
    2   bwa_mem_to_bam
    7
Alignment of sampleB_R1.fastq.gz and sampleB_R2.fastq.gz on BaL_AY713409.fasta with BWA version 0.7.12.

Alignment of sampleA_R1.fastq.gz and sampleA_R2.fastq.gz on BaL_AY713409.fasta with BWA version 0.7.12.

1 of 7 steps (14%) done
Genomic sorting of sampleB_unsorted.bam with samtools version 1.2.

Removing temporary output file /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/mapping_BaL/sampleB_unsorted.bam.
2 of 7 steps (29%) done
Indexing sampleB.bam.

3 of 7 steps (43%) done
4 of 7 steps (57%) done
Genomic sorting of sampleA_unsorted.bam with samtools version 1.2.

Removing temporary output file /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/mapping_BaL/sampleA_unsorted.bam.
5 of 7 steps (71%) done
Indexing sampleA.bam.

6 of 7 steps (86%) done
localrule all:
    input: /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/mapping_BaL/sampleB.bam.bai, /home/nico/labo/etudes/Optimal/data/mapping_BaL/sampleA.bam.bai

7 of 7 steps (100%) done
```

And finally get my correct messages:

- Alignment of sampleB_R1.fastq.gz and sampleB_R2.fastq.gz on
  BaL_AY713409.fasta with BWA version 0.7.12.
- Alignment of sampleA_R1.fastq.gz and sampleA_R2.fastq.gz on BaL_AY713409.fasta
  with BWA version 0.7.12.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly looked your code.

Why didn't the first one work out?

Look when you declare `fq1_ID` and `fq1`, same for sample 2. You didn't assign the same string. For `fq1` you add a repertory for the file witch is not present for fq1_ID so snakemake is searching it in the workdir (current directory if `-d` option is not set) a file name with your string. Beacuse these variables are in input section.

So by removing the two fq1/2_ID, it will erase all files searching problems.

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I succed with the pipeline removing the `fq1_ID` and `fq2_ID` variables in the `rule bwa_mem_to_bam` and replacing in the `message` of the rule `input.fq1_ID` and `input.fq2_ID` by `input.fq1` and `input.fq2`.

The message is less elegant, but the pipeline is running correctly. Still doesn't understand exactly where was the mistake, if someone can explain, I'm still listening!

The correct code for `rule bwa_mem_to_bam`:

```Python
rule bwa_mem_to_bam:
input:
    index = config["reference"]["index"],
    fasta = config["reference"]["fasta"],
    fq1 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R1."+config["fastqExtension"]),
    fq2 = join(config["fastqDir"], "{sample}_R2."+config["fastqExtension"])
output:
    temp(join(config["outputDir"], "{sample}.bamUnsorted"))
version:
    subprocess.getoutput(
    "man bwa | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 2"
    )
log:
    join(config["outputDir"], config["logDir"], "{sample}.bwa_mem.log")
message:
    "Alignment of {input.fq1} and {input.fq2} on {input.fasta} with BWA version {version}."
shell:
    "bwa mem {input.fasta} {input.fq1} {input.fq2} 2> {log} | samtools view -Sbh - > {output}"
```